# Kinect range capability

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, motion-detection

I'm thinking of trying something with the kinect but before I buy the equipment I had a simple feasibility question.

Would the kinect v2 be able to track hand movements in a very large room with lots of people?

The people would be sitting.

The room might be 10 times the size of a normal living room?  Would it be possible to mount the kinect high to get maximum range?

Does it work in dark, but not pitch black, rooms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My living room is about 5m by 5m. So you ask the question for 50m by 50m.
The Kinect v2 has a depth image resolution of 512 x 424 pixels with a fov of 70.6 x 60 degrees. So at a distance of 50m, 1 pixel has a size of `2*50m*tan(70.6/2)/512 = 14 cm`. This is the size of my hand. The Kinect won't be able to track this depth info, you will just see noice and won't be able to filter the correct depth pixels which are hands.

A different way to check this is from the specs of the depth range of the Kinect v2. This gives a depth range of .5–4.5 meters. Within this range it can track a maximum of six people. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/meetkinect/features.aspx